# Moving Magento site and encryption key?

Tags: configuration

ok... I have an ecommerce site that I like they way it looks and want to use it for another different domain/site. I only have a few products on the site and a couple users. I also haven't setup a payment system on this site.

I want to transfer the whole site and database to a new server/new url as a base for the new site... do I need to copy the same encryption key from the original site or make up a new one for the new site?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link that goes into detail about transferring your site to a new server.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/moving_magento_to_another_server

In the article you will find a sections talking about the config file.

**Config File-
"Only thing left is our config file. This file contains the encryption key, the user name and password to connect to the database. If the connection parameters are different between your old and new servers, then you need to edit this file to reflect the changes. The editing is straight forward as the password for the database connection is not encrypted. Now, let’s copy that over as well: "**

Sounds like the only settings you have to change from moving to new server are the connection parameters. The encryption key is connected to the database so it must stay the same.

Hope this help.

Comment: Does it matter if 2 different domains use the same encryption key then? thanks :)

Comment: No. The encryption key is unique to magneto instillation.